# How many times does a line intersect the zero set of a smooth function?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

So I am working with a smooth function $\psi: \Delta^{d-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Delta^{d-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is the simplex (nonnegative points which sum to 1), and a line $\gamma(t) = (1-t)\eta_0 + t\eta_1$, where $t\in[0,1]$, $\eta_0,\eta_1 \in \Delta^{d-1}$. I'm interested in knowing how many times the line $\gamma$ intersects the set $\psi^{-1}(0)$. Things I know:

1) unfortunately, $0$ is not a regular value of $\psi$, so I do not know that $\psi^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth manifold.

2) the point $\eta_0 \not\in \psi^{-1}(0)$, so in particular the line $\gamma$ doesn't fully align with $\psi^{-1}(0)$.

3) the function $\psi$ actually only depends on some fixed subset of components $\{j_1,...,j_s\} \subset \{1,...,d\}$ - the values in the other components do not contribute to the function value (which is why it is not a submersion).

Ideally, I'd have that they intersected only finitely or countably many times. Does anyone know of any results that may be useful here? Or perhaps more conditions on $\psi$ that would guarantee such a result? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily countable.  Let $E$ be any closed subset of $[0,1]$.  There is a smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = E$ (take a suitable infinite series of "bump functions", each nonzero on one of the intervals in $E^c$).
Take $\psi$ so that $\psi(\gamma(t)) = f(t)$; it doesn't matter what $\psi$ does off this line.